# What is discrete mathematics based on?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

I am interested in studying computer science after I graduate, and I am aware that, based on your occupation, it can be a math heavy field. I've looking into discrete mathematics, and am interested in what the basis of it is. Also, if anyone has any experience, could you recommend any books for studying?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: After you graduate college?  High school?

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean by "basis"?

Comment: Yeah, I mean high school. I have a few years left. By basis, I mean like is it based very strongly in Algebra, calculus, etc.(I know Algebra and Calculus are closely related) I'm trying to get an understanding of why it's considered fundamental to Computer Science.

Comment: @CaptainAmerica16 What if discrete math is the "basis" of those other things?

Comment: Are you being serious? Does that have something to do with it be called 'discrete' math?

Comment: If you are being serious, could you expand on that explanation?

Comment: @CaptainAmerica16 I'm being semi-serious. Topics that are touched on in discrete math or closely related fields such as formal logic, (finite) set theory, and computation itself are very close to foundational concerns. You could also make a pretty strong, if somewhat heterodox, case that computation or formal logic is the "basis" for all math. I am, though, poking a bit of fun at the common linear conception of mathematics. It is better to view it as a web of ideas and perspectives. Also polynomials with real coefficients, say, are *vastly* more complicated things than, say, finite graphs.

Comment: At any rate, it definitely is the case that most concepts in discrete mathematics do not necessarily rely on algebra or calculus, though both of these tools definitely *can* be applied to discrete math. Discrete math can, in turn, be applied to them for example by taking a syntactic view of polynomials or calculus expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This was actually very helpful. As for the question about the books for studying, I'll just refer to the linked question.

Comment: The last thing I will say is "discrete math" isn't really a field. The term usually refers to university courses that are more of a sampler of various other fields that are useful for theoretical computer science. Most of the fields touched upon are huge fields on their own, e.g. logic, proof theory, number theory, combinatorics, probability theory, set theory, graph theory. There aren't really "discrete mathematicians" but there are definitely logicians, graph theorists, and set theorists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elementary logic, elementary set theory, formal arithmetic (developed from Peano axioms), some basic "structures": order, graphs, etc.

- David Gries & Fred Schneider, [A Logical Approach to Discrete Math](https://books.google.it/books?id=103UBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Springer (1993);
- Jean Gallier, [Discrete Mathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=HXSjIP0OgCUC&printsec=frontcover), Springer (2011).